# How to determine what this backup item originally was?

Tags: windows-10, backup

I've recently had a scary blue screen and hardware failure experience, and I'm backing up my data so that i can properly troubleshoot my system. I came across an oddity in the Windows 10 backup list though:

[image]

The bottom item appears to just be a jumble of characters. How can I tell what this originally was? It looks like it could be some sort of corrupted folder, or a SID for something that was removed, but when I'm already having device issues, seeing this is a little concerning.

Comment: The best way to back-up data *and* all your applications, their data, local email, etc. is to make a *disk image*. There are a number of free utilities to do so, such as Macrium Reflect. This will not back up data in the cloud, but that is not needed for local use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a folder of OneDrive. That ID works as a folder that shows the files in your onedrive, You can also see the icon, its of Microsoft OneDrive. Only File Explorer views it as "OneDrive". CMD and PowerShell also reads it as "OneDrive"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sounds legit, I didn't even notice the OneDrive cloud icon on it. I can safely exclude it, as I don't use OneDrive. Thanks!